# Writing into consecutive rows in csv file through pandas python

Tags: python, pandas

How do keep writing into consecutive rows using `pandas.Dataframe`? I have the following function that is called consecutively and writes the given values into a .csv file but the values are overwritten in the same row. Is there a way i can specify it to write into consecutive rows?

```
def csv_writer(filename, OutputFolder):

    f = open(OutputFolder + '\Output_' + filename +'_LOG.txt')
    s = f.read()
    m = re.search("GHz\s+\=(.*)dB",s)
    if m:
        Lossval = float(m.group(1))
        print("Loss Value for filename " + filename + "is :", Lossval)
        params['Lossval'] = Lossval

    n = re.search("Impedance\s+\=(.*)ohms",s)
    if n:
        Zc = float(n.group(1))
        print("Impedance Value for filename " + filename + "is :", Zc)
        params['Zc'] = Zc

    print("The Target Impedance is", TargetImpedance)
    params['Target Impedance'] = TargetImpedance

    value.append(params.copy())

    df = pd.DataFrame(value)
    df.to_csv('Values.csv')

    Val = 1/(abs(Zc - TargetImpedance) + 100*Lossval)
    return Val
```

Comment: pass a file-object opened in append (`'a'`) mode. Better yet, ditch pandas (which is really over-kill here) and just use the `csv` module (which will still involve a file in append mode).

Comment: wait so I pass my file object f here?

Comment: `open('Values.csv', 'a')`

Comment: Wait I'm confused. Where do I open it?

Comment: `df.to_csv(open('Values.csv', 'a'))`

Comment: Oh! Thanks. I wasn't aware of this.

Comment: For some reason the column headers are getting printed again cuz of the appending.

Comment: yea. Because that's what `to_csv` does. Check out the documentation. There are *many many* arguments the `to_csv` method can take to tailor your output. But again, you almost certainly should ditch `pandas` for the `csv` module.

Comment: Okay I'll look at the csv module too! Thanks for your inputs

Comment: In either event, you'l proaably want to use an extra parameter in your function, something like `useheader` that controls whether or not your use a header...

Comment: Oh okay that makes sense. I'll look into it